# Calling function on same object from within event

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am playing around with RequireJS and creating a simple validation library.  I am returning an object full of functions but want one of these functions to be called from within an event handler that is placed by another function.

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    return {
        ...
        checkPageValidation: function(){
            //Check page validation, enable/disable submit button
            ...
        },
        addValidationToControl: function(controlId, validatingFunction, comparisonControlId){
            //Add the validation function to the focus out event
            var $control = $("#" + controlId);
            ...
            $control.focusout(function (evnt){
                let $this = $(this); //this is the control that fired the event
                if(validatingFunction($this.val()){
                    ...
                } else {
                    ...
                }
                checkPageValidation(); //How to call this function?
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How do I call the `checkPageValidation()` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference object while initialization, Instead create a constructor and call using this keyword inside it.

You can call the function using **this** keyword

```
this.checkPageValidation();
```

**OR**

Create a variable before returning

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
       var validation = function(){
            //Check page validation, enable/disable submit button
            ...
        };
    return {
        ...
        checkPageValidation: validation,
        addValidationToControl: function(controlId, validatingFunction, comparisonControlId){
            //Add the validation function to the focus out event
            var $control = $("#" + controlId);
            ...
            $control.focusout(function (evnt){
                let $this = $(this); //this is the control that fired the event
                if(validatingFunction($this.val()){
                    ...
                } else {
                    ...
                }
                validation(); //call using this keyword
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, `this` at that point is the `<input>` that fired the event therefore `Uncaught TypeError: this.checkPageValidation is not a function`

Comment: Edited kindly look into the changes

Comment: This still doesn't get around the issue that `this` is the html control and not the js object, therefore `this.validation()` doesn't exist.

Comment: When we are doing the second approach there is no need of this, you can call directly. There is No way to access the object literal that is currently being defined.